# Convert javascript template to pure javascript

Tags: java, javascript

By using java i want to convert  javascript template (i try to make ) to pure javascript

Here is example :
 Input

```
<? function test() 
{
    return "Just a message";
}
if("a"=="b")
{
?>
<h1><?=test()?></h1>
<?
}
?>
<?=test()?>

</head></html>
```

output pure js example

```
out.print("<html><head>");
function test() 
{
    return "Just a message";
}
out.print("<h1>");
if("a"=="b")
{
out.print(test());
}

out.print("</h1>");
out.print("</head></html>");
```

I need a function to convert javascript template to pure javascript an eval it later .
p/s
a example using javascript function here http://ejohn.org/blog/javascript-micro-templating/
but i'm not sure it work perfectly when given conplex template

Answer (score 1):

You can match every  pair. And each pair is javascript and the rest is outputted using out.print(...). A simple regex can do the job.

Or you can look at template engines which are fully tested and supported, such as: http://mustache.github.io/